# backbone events binding to buttons with in and out of template

Tags: backbone.js

In below example it has two buttons "Add" and "ClearAll".

```
       `http://jsfiddle.net/naveencgr/L3orucjm/3/`
```

"Add" button is inside the template which is loaded by backbone on view render and Clear All button is loaded normally as in html.

I had events for both the buttons in view, but click event on normally loaded button is not working . Why?

Answer (score 0):

i have seen this question asked in backbone github forum. I thibk it is designed this way. each backbone view events only involved with items inside the view.

in order to use the outside event you either put thie inner view into theoutter view or simple use jquery event for it. basically backbone authors believe this is more elegant and secure and this will not be changed at least for now.